# Salesforce for the Insurance industry - Architecture Question

Tags: design

- We are implementing Salesforce.com for our insurance company (we are resellers of other insurances) and we serve both B2B and B2C. We don't have the need to use/manage Cases. We are mostly interested on the implementation of the sales cycle.
- Very high level, how would you implement this? Using just opportunities,products and pricebooks or you would also involve Entitlement Management? What would be the benefit in that case?
- Is there something like fundamental when comes to sfdc implementation for insurance, that we are maybe missing?

Comment: I have experience in this area. Depending on how you do your rating engine s and what type of insurance you provide (property & casualty, etc) you will not be able to use Products and Pricebooks as they come out of the box with SFDC as insurance rates are typically determined by complex rating engines that the actuaries configure based on tons of data. You will most likely need to implement an integration into your risk & rating engines against a small set of custom objects you build.

Comment: The same problem also applies to cases / entitlements as each State has its own catalogue of complex insurance regulations around claims (aka Cases in SFDC). There is a great deal of customization that is required to ensure your cases meet all the legal requirements required by each state and often the rules engine is way to large to run with Entitlements.

Comment: To give you some context, at an insurance company I worked at we used Cases as the Claim Object, and a custom object called Policy that held the sold policies. We did not use Opportunities at all in our Sales Cycle as it did not make sense. Way too much discovery and data analysis went into that decision for a huge implementation to type out in StackExchange. Hope this helps you at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you, cases could be the equivalent of claims management for your customers, problems with billing issues, or tracking any kind of issue that requires follow-up with a customer since they'll see you as their point of contact with the insurance companies that you represent.

Since I have some cursory familiarity with your industry, let's assume you broker commercial insurance for small to medium sized businesses. In Salesforce, entitlement is closely linked to cases. It could be viewed as a situation of what *insurance coverage* and *additional services* have your customers paid you *premiums and fees* for along with *what periods are covered* by the *premiums they've paid* for their *policies* and what *services* do the *fees* cover that they've *paid you*?

A client may have paid you for E&O coverage involving work they performed for their customers for a particular calendar year. That year may have been 5 years ago, but the coverage for the work they did that year might still exist for another 15 years (20 years total) under the terms of the policy they paid you during that calendar year. Similarly, a widget manufacturer might purchase catastrophic claims coverage for defects liability in case someone is injured by a defective widget and files suit against the company down the road.

Until claims can no longer be filed against those policies, your customers would still have an entitlement to services under them. If they were to contact you about filing a claim, you'd create a case to track it with the insurer.